# Program not getting terminated

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I've been doing a Java MOOC, and I'm stuck on a submission as my program does not terminate although I get desired output.

The problem says:

> Create a method called `printText` which prints the phrase "In a hole in the ground there lived a method" and a newline. Then expand the program so that the main program asks the user for the number of times the phrase will be printed (i.e. how many times the method will be called).

I think the problem might be in my while loop not getting terminated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many times?");
    int n = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    int a = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (a < n) {
            printText();
            a++;
        }
    }
}

public static void printText() {
    System.out.println("In a hole in the ground there lived a method");
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `while (true)` with `while(a < n)` and remove the `if-statement`, or add `else{break;}` to your current code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `a < n` condition should be associated with your loop. Although the `if` ensures that `printText()` is only called `n` times, it does not prevent the infinite loop from continuing forever:

```
while (a < n) {
    printText();
    a++;
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep your infinite loop but `break` when `a >= n`:

```
while (true) {
    if (a < n) {
        printText();
        a++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

But the first solution is more readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost on track, get rid of outer loop while loop and change `if (a < n)` to `while(a<n)`

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many times?");
        int n = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        int a = 0;
        while(a < n) {
                printText();
                a++;


        }

    }
    public static void printText() {

        System.out.println("In a hole in the ground there lived a method");
    }
}
```